# parse error: syntax error: unexpected ';' on line 25

Tags: php, parse-error

now i just need to find out why it says Old Version Every time even when $a = true
if a is true it should do the if block and none of the others. maybe the version needs to be a post variable i will try it

```
<?php
$launcherv = "13";
$gamev = "1326382442000";
$sessid = math.rand(1, 1000000000000000);
$ticket = math.rand(1, 1000000000000);
$user =      "";
$password =  "";
$version =   "";
$a = false;
$b = false;
$c = false;


if ($version == $launcherv){
$a = true;

} else {
$a = false;

}
if ($user == ""){
$b = false;

} else {


$b = 'true';

}
if ($password == ""){
$c = false;

} else {
$c = true;

}




if ($a && $b && $c){
echo ($gamev.":".$ticket.":".$user.":".$sessid);
}
elseif(!$a){
echo "Old Version";
}
elseif(!$b){
echo "Bad Login";
}
elseif(!$c){
echo "Bad Login";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this...

```
 else (
>>>$b = 'true';>>> error?

)
```

You should have...

```
else {
  $b = 'true';
}
```

It gets an error because it isn't expecting the end of the line to be inside parens.

Comment: i put that there to show where the error was

Comment: Yes, but you need curly braces `{}` instead of parens `()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line right above the error. used a paren instead of curly brace

```
} else (
```

Comment: o crud eclipse i couldnt see that thanks!!!!!!

Comment: @CoffeeRain yes? it should be `else { _code_ }` but the OP accidently did `else ( _code_ )`

Comment: Sorry, I'll delete that. I thought you said **Use** a paren instead of a curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use curly brackets for control structures:

```
} else {
   $b = 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `(` after the else on the preceeding line. That should be `{` with a matching closing `}`

Comment: now i get "Old version ooutput even wnen $a = 'true'"

Comment: i did not know you could just use if($a), like in java. can you use !$a also? for toggles?

Answer (score 0):

In php, blocks are always delimited by curly braces `{`, not round parentheses `(`. Take a closer look:

```
} else ( // <---
   $b = 'true';
) // <--
```

You want:

```
} else {
   $b = 'true';
}
```

Also note that it's a bad idea to use the strings `'true'` and `'false'` as magical values. Instead of

```
if ($version >= $launcherv){
    $a = 'true';
} else {
    $a = 'false';
}
...
if ($a == 'true') {
```

You should really use [boolean values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

```
if ($version >= $launcherv){
    $a = true;
} else {
    $a = false;
}
...
if ($a) { // or ! $a   for the opposite
```

You can simplify this code even further:

```
$a = $version >= $launcherv;
...
if ($a) { // or ! $a   for the opposite
```

The short variables are likely to confuse [future readers](http://geekandpoke.typepad.com/geekandpoke/2008/01/one-year-in-a-i.html). Therefore, you can even write:

```
...
if ($version >= $launcherv) {
```

Comment: i put those there so you could see where the error was

Comment: @user1116644 You seem to be confusing the `<<<`. The parentheses are the problem.

Comment: i didnt use bolean values because at first i thougt th at was the problem, and i never changed it back

Comment: That technique is known as [shotgun debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging) and should be avoided. To find an error, make your code shorter and simpler, not more complicated.